# Why is my custom centos kernel not booting? No source changes were made

Tags: linux, centos, grub, kernel, linux-kernel

I followed this guide to rebuild my 3.10.0-327 kernel (CentOS 7.2): https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Custom_Kernel

I will be making changes to it, but even if I make no source changes, it does not boot after install. After I select my kernel in grub, I just get a black screen with a blinking cursor in the upper left hand corner. Any idea where I should look to further investigate this?

When I start in single-user mode, I only see this:

```
Probing EDD (edd=off to disable)... ok
_
```

where _ is the blinking cursor.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/708447/probing-edd-boot-message-stays-for-ten-minutes-on-centos-6-6 or maybe https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/new-to-linux-getting-problem-on-start-up-probing-edd-edd%3Doff-to-disable-4175572595/